# Image load delay on iphone and ipad

Tags: iphone, ipad, image-loading

A set of (5) navigation buttons are slow to load on iphone and ipad. Each button consist of a common background image, overlaid with the specific icon for that button, there is also a mouseover version swapped in with javascript. Background and foreground images are small (all <1kb).

When testing on iPhone and iPad, there is usually a delay (from 1 to 3 seconds, rarely longer). During this transitional time, the navigation buttons turn into something else.

On the iPad, buttons turn into a rectangular shape about half the height of the button containing a question mark, giving the impression of a missing image.

On the iPhone, buttons turn into rectangular shapes too, but empty, with exception of the final button (which shows the alt text "Next").

No such delay is encountered on chrome, firefox, IE on windows.

I tried pre-loading the images, also hiding the button container until onload occurs, both to no avail.

Comment: What language/software are you asking about?

Comment: Do you have code that demonstrates what you've tried?

Comment: It is a HTML5 Web page. Example image code:
<img onmouseout="unhover(this, '../img/butools.png');" onmouseover="hover(this, '../img/butools_onMouseOver.png');" title="Tools" alt="tools" src="../img/butools.png">

The images share a common background image, with different foregrounds per button. The image code is written by javascript document.write statements, as a version of the site has to be delivered offline.